# Is there a list of Pesukim from Tanakh, used on the Sidur?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, tanach, prayer-book

This is my first question on the site, kol hakavod to the initiative!

I am looking for a complete list of Biblical Verses, Pesukim from the Tanakh, in order like any index, that appear on the Sidur, (considering the different Nusachim).

I looked at Netiv Binah and among the huge index, doesn't have an Index on Bublical Sources. I didn't find it on Google either.

Does anyone know some book, Commentaries to Sidur, Prayer Encyclopedia, etc??

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Natan, and thanks for the interesting question! Hopefully you have your response already. I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

And if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour)